# Cómo validar una hora introducida por el usuario con formato HH:MM

Tags: python, regex, validación, datetime

Trato de validar dos horas introducidas por el usuario para que sea exclusivamente en formato `HH:MM`.

Este es mi código, pero no funciona:

```
def validateDate(date1, date2):  
    try:  
        time_re = re.compile(r'^(1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')  
        match(time_re, date1)  
        match(time_re, date2)  
    except :  
        print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tiene mucho sentido usar una expresión regular para validar horas o fechas. Existen funciones para eso, como se muestra en la [respuesta de @Madh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32966/127).

Sin embargo, sólo para completar la respuesta, marco algunas cosas que había que corregir en el código para que funcione:

1. La función [match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) no es global. Se debe usar `re.match(time_re, date1)` o `time_re.match(date1)`
2. [try y except](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html) se usan para capturar excepciones. Sin embargo, cuando un texto no coincide con una expresión regular, no dispara una excepción, simplemente devuelve `false`, por lo que no ibas a capturarlo de esa forma.
3. No es un error, pero probablemente quieras aceptar horas que empiezan con `0`, como `01:23`. Para eso, hay que incluirlo en el primer caracter:

   ```
   ^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
   ```
4. Sólo como recomendación:

   - [match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) devuelve las coincidencias sólo cuando el *inicio* del texto coincide con el regex. En ese caso, es innecesario utilizar `^`. Sin embargo, como regla general, te recomiendo usar [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) cuando quieras el mismo comportamiento que en otros lenguajes.
   - Se debería evitar el uso de [grupos](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) cuando no se utilizan. Si sólo se quiere agrupar una parte del patrón, conviene usar `(?:`…`)`.

Código:

```python
import re

def validateDate(date1, date2):  
    time_re = re.compile(r'^(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$')
    return time_re.search(date1) and time_re.search(date2)


print "Ej 1"
if not validateDate("01:59", "21:08"):
    print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"

print "Ej 2"
if not validateDate("01:60", "21:08"):
    print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"

print "Ej 3"
if not validateDate("01:59", "24:08"):
    print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
```

Resultado:

```
Ej 1
Ej 2
Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm 

Ej 3
Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm
```

Demo:

<kbd>[rextester.com](http://rextester.com/PVEM39217)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente explicación, y muchas gracias por la ayuda de ambos. :))

Comment: @Rasimus.84 `^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$`

Comment: Sale, Gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

Es posible hacerlo sin utilizar una expresión regular.

```
import time

def isValidTime(data):
    try:
        time.strptime(data, "%H:%M")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Quedando en tú código algo así:

```
if not (isValidTime(date1) and isValidTime(date2)):
    print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
```

Saludos.

Comment: Eso también funcionaria introduciendo H:MM & H:MM, no?

Comment: La condición del `if` debería ser `if not isValidTime(date1) or not isValidTime(date2):` (o usar un paréntesis y dejar el `not` afuera)

Comment: def openAuto(usrHrOp, usrHrCl):
usrHrOp = raw_input("Introduzca hora para activar en formato 'hh:mm': \n")
 usrHrCl = raw_input("Introduzca hora para desactivar en formato 'hh:mm': \n")
if not (validateDate(usrHrOp) and validateDate(usrHrCl)):
     print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
  #Abrir!
  while (usrHrOp != actual):
......
Saben por que marca?
print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Rasimus.84 porque después del `if`, las instrucciones que van dentro del mismo tienen que tener un nivel más de tabulación

Answer (score 0):

```
def validateDate(date1, date2):  
    try:  
        time_re = re.compile(r'^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')  
        match(time_re, date1)  
        match(time_re, date2)  
    except :  
        print "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm \n"
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada de baja calidad por la falta de una explicación de estos cambios que has realizado. Agrega una descripción de los mismos a la respuesta para que todos lo podamos entender, gracias!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).